# ASP.NET web service parameter type

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

How to I control parameter type tag in ASP.NET web service? I get **< xml>string< /xml>** in one web application and **< data>string< /data>** in other... Is there a way to control this?

```
[WebMethod]
public bool TestFunction(string xml)
{
    //DO SOMETHING
    return true;
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <TestFunction xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <xml>string</xml> //<data>string</data>
    </TestFunction>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

edit: I forgot to rename function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any method is exposed using the parameter names you specify. If you change your method to `public bool TestFunction(string FooBar)`, then the string will be in a `<FooBar>string</FooBar>` tag in the resulting XML.

When you are using WCF you can change this behavior using Message Contracts or applying a MessageParameter to instruct the serializer to use an alternate name:

```
public bool TestFunction([MessageParameter(Name="YourName")]string xml)
```

However, I don't know whether this also applies to ASP.Net web services.

Comment: Yes it was a parameter name, I thought it has something to do with transport data type, because of the name.